# How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql

I have 2 triggers on one table; one works for INSERTs :

```
CREATE TRIGGER "get_user_name"
AFTER INSERT ON "field_data"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "add_info"();
```

This updates some values in the table.
And one for UPDATEs (to fill a history table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER "set_history"
BEFORE UPDATE ON "field_data"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "gener_history"();
```

The problem is that when I insert a new row in the table the procedure `"add_info"()` makes an update and therefore fires the second trigger, which ends with an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  record "new" has no field "field1"
> ```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: It sounds like an error in the trigger logic. Could you show the trigger procedure that throws it?

Comment: yes it does - what do you get if you just `update` a row? I'd expect the same error.

Comment: You both are right: it was an error in my second trigger.  My problem is solved but nevertheless I was thinking of something like the pg_trigger_depth() proposed by @Akash, which I need to test further now, because for the moment my trigger doesn't do anything at all when I use this test.  Thanks to all of you !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<sup>(Obvious error in the trigger logic aside.)</sup>
In Postgres **9.2** or later, use the function [**`pg_trigger_depth()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) that [Akash](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/16020/akash) already mentioned in a **condition on the trigger itself** (instead of the body of the trigger function), so that the trigger function is not even executed when called from another trigger (including itself - so also preventing loops).
This typically performs better and is simpler and cleaner:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_history
BEFORE UPDATE ON field_data
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)
EXECUTE FUNCTION gener_history();
```

In Postgres 10 or older use the keyword `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`. See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307492/trigger-uses-a-procedure-or-a-function/307500#307500)

The expression `pg_trigger_depth() < 1` is evaluated *before* the trigger function is entered. So it evaluates to 0 in the first call. When called from another trigger, the value is higher and the trigger function is not executed.

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding the solution proposed by @Akash, as I said in a comment above, the test on pg_trigger_depth() = 0 didn't give me any result, but I found that preceding my code inside the body of the trigger function by "IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN RETURN NEW; END IF;" as explained here : http://www.depesz.com/2012/02/01/waiting-for-9-2-trigger-depth/ does work.  I'm mentioning this for future users, but your solution looks even simpler, and I will test it asap.

Comment: @dd_a: `pg_trigger_depth() = 0` in Akash's answer makes no sense inside a trigger function. I added a comment there and more explanation to my answer. My solution should be simpler and faster for your use case than what Depesz presented in his blog.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat: Please ask new questions as new *questions*. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: **@ErwinBrandstetter**: I apologize.  I didn't think my questions worthy of a whole new thread as they were in the context of the current discussion.  I will remove my comment and migrate the questions to a new thread.

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want the update trigger to be executed when the its called from within the insert trigger, you can surround your statements with a condition of `pg_trigger_depth()` which returns the depth, **which wont be 0 when you are running the trigger directly/indirectly from another trigger**.

So, within your function `gener_history()`, you can do something like this

```
IF pg_trigger_depth() = 1 THEN
.. your statements..
END IF;
```

Here's another example: http://www.depesz.com/2012/02/01/waiting-for-9-2-trigger-depth/

Comment: It has to be noted that `pg_trigger_depth() = 0` inside a trigger is always false because the minimum trigger depth is **1** there. You only get 0 outside of a trigger.

Comment: right, seems I made a mistake, I've correct it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION #1

Remove the `AFTER INSERT` trigger and call `add_info` from your app

### SUGGESTION #2

Change the `AFTER INSERT` trigger into `BEFORE INSERT`