# Preventing Infinite Trigger Loops in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I am working with two PostgreSQL databases (one internal and one on our company Web server) where I am attempting to share data between the two instances through the use of triggers.  The databases have a "shared" table (basically a replica of the same table with pretty much the same data on both servers).  When our in-house representatives update the table, it successfully updates  the Web server's database via `dblink` without a problem.

The issue, however, is when I try to introduce a trigger on the Web server to pass updated values back to the internal server.  I always seem to end up triggering an infinite loop (pun intended), which then forces me to shut down both PGSQL instances so that I can DROP the problem trigger.  I have tried a number of ways to prevent the loop from occurring, including making the WHERE clause as specific as I believe I can, but I can't seem to get around this issue.

After a lot of research, I found [this thread on this SE site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger) (and a few other similar threads/posts on other sites) which indicate that one possible way to prevent a loop is to use the `pg_trigger_depth()` function to catch when a trigger is being executed by another trigger.  That sounds great, except for one fatal issue: my internal PGSQL database is running v9.1 (my Web server is running 9.2).

Based on my initial testing, I'm assuming that `pg_trigger_depth()` cannot return a "correct" value when the trigger is being called from a server that doesn't support the function (or possibly if it is being called across the `dblink` connection - I'm not certain what the limiting factor is in this environment).

So, my question, I suppose, is this: Is there any way to emulate the `pg_trigger_depth()` function in this type cross-database scenario to prevent an infinite loop?  Failing that, does anyone have any other suggestions for a way to keep this from locking up my database servers?

Here are some (redacted) basics of the functions in question:

**THIS TRIGGER FUNCTION ON THE WEB SERVER** *(I currently don't have an actual trigger created for this one to prevent it from creating the dreaded infinite loop)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webschema.update_inhouse_billing()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  myconnect text[];
  myint integer;

BEGIN
select * into myconnect from dblink.dblink_get_connections();
if (myconnect[1] is null )  then
 perform dblink.dblink_connect('myconn','inhousedb');
end if;

BEGIN
select * from dblink.dblink('myconn','select inhouseschema.updatebilling(' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."UserID")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."Month")           || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count1")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count2")          || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count3")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."CalcAmount")      || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."OverrideAmount")  || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Posted")          || ')') as t(a integer) into myint;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN others THEN
     RETURN NEW;

END;    
RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

**CALLS THIS FUNCTION ON THE IN-HOUSE DATABASE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inhouseschema.updatebilling(userid integer, month integer, count1 integer, count2 integer, count3 integer, calcamount numeric, overrideamount numeric, posted integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  mycount integer;
BEGIN
    UPDATE inhouseschema.billing b SET 
        "Count1"         = $3,
        "Count2"         = $4,
        "Count3"         = $5,
        "CalcAmount"     = $6,
        "OverrideAmount" = $7,
        "Posted"         = $8
    WHERE (b."UserID" = $1 AND b."Month" = $2 AND b."Paid" IS NULL) 
    AND b."Count1" <> $3 AND b."Count2" <> $4 AND b."Count3" <> $5 AND b."CalcAmount" <> $6;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS mycount = ROW_COUNT;
RETURN mycount;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

**THIS TRIGGER FUNCTION ON THE IN-HOUSE SERVER**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inhouseschema.update_web_billing()

  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  myconnect text[];
  myint integer;
BEGIN

select * into myconnect from dblink.dblink_get_connections();
if (myconnect[1] is null )  then
 perform dblink.dblink_connect('myconn','webserverdb');
end if;

BEGIN
select * from dblink.dblink('myconn','select webschema.updatebilling(' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."UserID")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."Month")           || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count1")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count2")          || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Count3")          || ',' || 
     quote_nullable(NEW."CalcAmount")      || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."OverrideAmount")  || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Posted")          || ',' ||
     quote_nullable(NEW."Paid")            || ')') as t(a integer) into myint;         

EXCEPTION
   WHEN others THEN
     RETURN NEW;

END;    
RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

**CALLS THIS FUNCTION ON THE WEB SERVER DATABASE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webschema.updatebilling(userid integer, month integer, count1 integer, count2 integer, count3 integer, calcamount numeric, overrideamount numeric, posted integer, paid integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  mycount integer;
BEGIN

UPDATE webschema.billing b SET 
    "Count1"         = $3,
    "Count2"         = $4,
    "Count3"         = $5,
    "CalcAmount"     = $6,
    "OverrideAmount" = $7,
    "Posted"         = $8,
    "Paid"           = $9
WHERE (b."UserID" = $1 AND b."Month" = $2);

GET DIAGNOSTICS mycount = ROW_COUNT;
RETURN mycount;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

I pretty much want the data from our in-house database to be the "final authority" as our Accounting Department have an interface for approving the information posted and flagging it as "paid", but I want the information from the Web site to come in and update the in-house database as long as it hasn't been marked as paid.

The trigger I've been trying to set up on the Web server is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER billing_update_inhouse AFTER UPDATE ON webschema.billing FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE webschema.update_inhouse_billing();
```

And the trigger (that appears to be working correctly) on the in-house server is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER billing_update_web AFTER UPDATE ON inhouseschema.billing FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inhouseschema.update_web_billing();
```

Okay, so I guess that's about it.  There may be a typo or two in the above code with my redactions, but this should be pretty much it.  Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts on how I might be able to resolve this issue once and for all?

Comment: I suppose I probably should have prefaced this with the disclaimer: "this is my first real attempt to work with triggers _ever_, so if there's an even better way to go about this, I'm all ears.

Comment: I have one "dumb" question about the `inhouseschema.updatebilling` I posted above: If the values in the database are NULL, but the parameter values are not, will PostgreSQL recognize them as "`<>`"?  I've run into cases in other databases where a NULL value has to be explicitly checked for in addition to the "not equal" condition.

Comment: You can just `SET myapp.row_origin = 'webapp'` or `SET myapp.row_origin = 'otherthing'` before the trigger, and in the trigger use `current_setting('myapp.row_origin')` to detect that. You'll want to set a global default in `postgresql.conf` or via `alter database ... set ...` so that it's never undefined.

Comment: **@CraigRinger**: Thank you for the suggestion, but allow me to show my ignorance here.  If I choose to go the `ALTER DATABASE` route, would I actually go run a query (using my examples above) that states something like `ALTER DATABASE webserverdb SET myapp.row_origin = 'web'` (and another where `row_origin = inhouse`), or am I misunderstanding?  After that has been set, then, for example on the Web server's trigger function, would I put in my trigger functions, before the first `BEGIN` statement, something like `IF current_setting('myapp.row_origin') = 'web' THEN...`?

Comment: Correction to above: put the `IF...THEN` conditional statement _after_ the first `BEGIN` statement. Regardless, I'm reading up on the `SET` command.  I'm still not sure about setting up the default setting for `myapp.row_origin`, but are you suggesting something like this on the `update_inhouse_billing()` trigger function? `BEGIN IF current_settings('myapp.row_origin') = 'web' THEN select * into myconnect...` then `BEGIN SET myapp.row_origin = 'inhouse' select * from dblink.dblink...`. Then do the opposite in `update_web_billing()` (`IF current_settings('myapp.row_origin') = 'inhouse'...`)?