# Prevent explicit insert into serial columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, permissions, sequence

I want to prevent explicit inserts into serial columns. I have come up to the following trigger:

```
drop table test_table;

create table test_table(
id bigserial primary key,
foobar text
);

create or replace function serial_id_check() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    if new.id != currval(TG_TABLE_NAME||'_id_seq') then
        raise exception 'Explicit insert into serial id, currval = %, tried to insert = %', currval(TG_TABLE_NAME||'_id_seq'), new.id;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger test_table_serial_id_check
before insert on test_table
for each row
execute procedure serial_id_check();
```

Maybe there is a better approach? Maybe this approach is broken and this cannot be achieved at all?

P.S. I also think about not granting rights for the insert and update, but only for pgplsql procedure for inserting/updating - but this approach is not possible for me right now.

Comment: Why do you want this?  And what is missing from your trigger?

Comment: This might break for multi-valued inserts, insert into ... select ... , etc. Not sure.

Comment: Can you please explain about multi-valued inserts?

Comment: with d as (
        select 'pgadmin' as foo
        union all select 'pgadmin'
        union all select 'pgadmin'
    )
    insert into test_table(foobar)
    select foo from d;

This query works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In **Postgres 10** or later, consider an `IDENTITY` column instead. Like:

```
id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

See:

- [What are Identity Columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158988/what-are-identity-columns)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

---

Original answer for older versions:

#### [Updateable View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS)

In **Postgres 9.4**, views are automatically updatable *per column*. I.e., as long as basic conditions are met, columns are automatically updatable for plain references to underlying columns. Expressions are not. We can exploit this feature:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, foobar text
);

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT id * 1 AS id  -- id unchanged but not updatable!
     , foobar
FROM   test_table;
```

By multiplying `id` with `1`, the value is unchanged but the column is not automatically updatable any more.

- `REVOKE` `INSERT` / `UPDATE` privileges on `test_table` from your users.
- Make another role holding those privileges ***own*** the view.
- `GRANT INSERT` / `UPDATE` on `test_view` to your users.

Now they can do everything, but they cannot manually set or alter the value in `id`. It's your choice how to handle `DELETE`.

This **simple and quick solution** works out of the box in Postgres 9.4. Automatically updatable views were introduced with Postgres 9.3, but all columns need to be updatable in that version for the feature to work.

In **Postgres 9.3 or older**, provide an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger or an unconditional `ON INSERT DO INSTEAD` rule.

While writing rules / triggers manually, you don't need the `id * 1` trick. You might want to use this even in Postgres 9.4+ to fine-tune functionality. Example:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view1 AS TABLE test_table;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE ins_up AS
 ON INSERT TO test_view1 DO INSTEAD
INSERT INTO test_table (foobar) VALUES (NEW.foobar);
```

Now, `INSERT` on the view is possible, but not yet `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Write more rules if you want that.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9025d/1)  (Postgres 9.6)

Important **difference**: while the automatically updatable view rejects attempts to `INSERT` / `UPDATE` values in `id` with an *exception*, the demonstrated `RULE` simply *ignores* values for `id` and proceeds without exception.

#### Simple trigger

Alternatively, you could simply overwrite the serial column with the next value from its sequence *unconditionally*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION force_serial_id()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME), 'id'));
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

That's simpler and cheaper and less error-prone than trying to be smart about it. [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to safely escape otherwise illegal names (also defends against SQL injection).

Like [@dezso commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116054/prevent-explicit-insert-into-serial-columns/116091?noredirect=1#comment211013_116091), this burns *two* numbers per row in normal operation with a `serial` column because a default is fetched *before* the trigger function kicks in. Typically, gaps in a sequence should not be a problem (to be expected anyway), but you can avoid the side effect by removing the `DEFAULT` from the column. Then you rely on the trigger exclusively.

You could fine-tune the `UPDATE` case with a separate trigger and a condition on the trigger itself `WHEN (OLD.id <> NEW.id)`. Syntax example:

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger/103661#103661)

Note the use of [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE), which won't break like your original for non-basic identifiers. Think of `"MyTable"` or a non-default sequence name. Still assuming the column name `id` which I personally *never* use since it's not descriptive.

Comment: The funny side effect of this trigger is that it skips a value in the sequence when you rely on `nextval()` as default.  Otherwise very good ideas.

Comment: @dezso: Good catch. I added a bit to address that.

Comment: For the trigger I would recommend the more robust `NEW.id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '"', 'id'));` It took me some debbuging to realize this caused the issue.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam: Good point. Better yet: `quote_ident()`.  See update.

Comment: thanks, i've learned something new

Comment: The problem with the IDENTITY solution is that it generate errors on duplicate values: cannot insert into column "id"; DETAIL: column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS. HINT: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override. Haha, I cant make QGIS to use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE in its transactions.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam: Nothing to do with "duplicate values". You cannot insert given values because `GENERATED ALWAYS` makes it so. That's what this question is about: "Prevent explicit insert into serial columns". You seem to have a different case. Maybe `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` works for you, maybe not. Present your case in a new question if you need help. You can always reference this one for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter True, the question was different. I am to enforce unique serial value over an explicitly given any value (ideally including NULL) on a (de facto) primary key. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

## [Identity Columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158988/2639)

This isn't *exactly* an answer *yet*, but what you want is `GENERATED ALWAYS`. And, it's on its way, maybe as soon as the next release of PostgreSQL, PostgreSQL 10

```
CREATE TABLE itest4 (
  a int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  b text
);
```

Syntax stolen verbatum from the [emails about the patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com#6adbacbf-73bc-dd1a-2033-63409180fd18@2ndquadrant.com).

Track the [issue in the commitfest here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158988/2639).

From the SQL Spec,

```
If <identity column specification> is specified, then:
i) An indication that the column is an identity column.
ii) If ALWAYS is specified, then an indication that values are always generated.
iii) If BY DEFAULT is specified, then an indication that values are generated by default.
iv) The General Rules of Subclause 9.26, “Creation of a sequence generator”, are applied with
SGO as OPTIONS and ICT as DATA TYPE; let the descriptor of the sequence generator SG be
the SEQGENDESC returned from the application of those General Rules.
```

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer is all good, but when trying to troubleshoot a scenario where code from somewhere appears to be inserting explicit ID values and thereby breaking the sequence down the road, you really want to raise an error to the offending code instead of simply fixing the problem on the fly (or rewriting everything to use a view).

The OPs own solution does break in the scenario where you do multiple inserts via either `INSERT INTO table (col2) VALUES ('val'), ('val')` or `INSERT INTO table (col2) SELECT somefield FROM anothertable`.

This slight fix to the trigger condition fixes that issue. Also note the use of `pg_get_serial_sequence` to more reliably determine the name of the sequence. (Note that `pg_get_serial_sequence` relies on the sequence's `OWNED BY` property being correctly set.)

```
create or replace function serial_id_check() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    if new.id > currval(pg_get_serial_sequence(TG_TABLE_NAME, 'id')) then
        raise exception 'Explicit insert into serial id, currval = %, tried to insert = %', currval(pg_get_serial_sequence(TG_TABLE_NAME, 'id')), new.id;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```