# How to auto-increment a serial column ON UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sequence

When [creating a sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createsequence.html) in Postgres 10, how do you auto-increment on updates? (Not just assign the next higher number for the next inserted row.)

For example, suppose I create the following table and sequence found on [this page](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/):

```
CREATE TABLE fruits(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO fruits(name) VALUES('Orange');
INSERT INTO fruits(id,name)  VALUES(DEFAULT,'Apple');

SELECT * FROM fruits;

 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | Apple
  2 | Orange
(2 rows)
```

As you can see it correctly auto-increments the "id" column by one on inserts.  However, if I do an update like:

```
update fruits 
set name = 'Orange2'
where name = 'Orange';

SELECT * FROM fruits;

    
                                                 id |  name
                                                ----+--------
                                                  1 | Apple
   How do I get this to auto-increment to 3? -->  2 | Orange2   
    (2 rows)
```

As you can see above, the row with id=2 has not been updated to id=3.  How do I create a sequence that will auto-increment on updates?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with that?

Comment: The most correct answer is **don't**. It's an anti-pattern. Whatever your use case is, stop it. If you really must, see the [answers below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294785/95344), but the better answer is you probably want a different design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an unusual request, because one wouldn't typically want to *change* an existing serial ID. (The PK, no less!)
But to answer the question: Use a **[trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)**.

Example trigger function & trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_next_id_on_update()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.fruits', 'id'));
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER next_id_on_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON fruits
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_next_id_on_update();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=871d2b1be9627095a15f07841dcb90b6)* (for Postgres 10)

Of course, this overwrites any changes to the `id` column that may have been made in the same `UPDATE`.

And it does not exactly "auto-increment". It assigns the next free number from the attached `SEQUENCE`. Assuming that's what you meant.

Note the `WHEN` condition: the trigger is only fired when the `name` actually changes. (Wouldn't want to change the ID for other updates, would you?) Related:

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger/103661#103661)
- [Fire trigger on update of columnA or ColumnB or ColumnC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436314/939860)

You can make the trigger function work for any given table (with a `serial` named `id`) by using the name of the triggering table (safely!):

```
   ...
   NEW.id := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence(quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA)
                                  || '.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME), 'id'));
   ...
```

Read the [manual about trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).
Related:

- [Prevent explicit insert into serial columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116054/prevent-explicit-insert-into-serial-columns/116091#116091)

Or make it less generic and a bit faster by hard-coding the name of the `SEQUENCE`:

```
   ...
   NEW.id := nextval('public.fruits_id_seq');
   ...
```

You decide what's safe and appropriate in your environment.

But your `UPDATE` example makes more sense with a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) on `fruits.name`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.fruits (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, name varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE -- !
);
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to explicitly update it you can use the keyword `DEFAULT`

```
update fruits 
set name = 'Orange2', id=DEFAULT
where name = 'Orange';
```

if you want to implicitly update it use a trigger like in the other answer.